# Can I use Wheel to ship a Python 3.x package to 2.7 if the source code is translatable but the setup is not?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pypi, python-packaging, python-wheel

I am building a Python package that I wish to be interoperable among Python 2 & 3.

In the source code directory I'm only using code which can be run in both 2.7 and 3.x, however, in the package-definition level (such as in `setup.py`) I'm not really caring about interoperability and am using more modern modules not necessarily backwards compatible with versions <2.7 such as `setuptools` and `pathlib`.

As far as I know, `setup.py` gets executed once `pip install`s a module, however,requiring something from `setup.py` in the source code after locally installing my package, I observed that the functionality-relevant code has no access to information available only in its parent directory where the package definition is located, which makes me believe these are abstracted.

If I use `wheel` to build the package into a Python 2.7 executable, can I expect it to be run in version 2.7 by anyone who downloads it without any further hassles?

If not, what should be my strategy?

Comment: perhaps you could make `setup.py` a thin wrapper which brings in the real 2.7 or 3.x code at runtime

Comment: So I would conditionally execute some blocks of code inside `setup.py` according to version? How would a package builder such as wheel respond to it? Could conditional install of packages in `setup.py` serve the same purpose?

Comment: I guess this would break if one tries to install your project under Python 2.7 from a _source distribution_ (`sdist`), but would be fine when installing from a _wheel_. Because installing from a sdist does trigger the execution of `setup.py`, while installing from a wheel does not (wheel distribution archives do not even contain the `setup.py` file). The general recommendation is to always distribute at least the `sdist`. And so I would think that you really should make your `setup.py` compatible with all Python interpreter versions targeted (so it should be compatible with Python 2.7).

Comment: @sinoroc seems this answers the question. If you add this as an answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would break if one tries to install your project under Python 2.7 from a "*source distribution* (`sdist`)", but would be fine when installing from a "*wheel*". Because installing from a sdist does trigger the execution of the setup script (`setup.py`), while installing from a wheel does not (wheel distribution archives do not even contain the setup script). This is the case because your "*build back-end*" seems to be *setuptools*, with other build back-ends the behavior might be a bit different.

In any case, the general recommendation in the Python packaging ecosystem is to always distribute at least the sdist.

And so I would think that you really should make your `setup.py` compatible with all Python interpreter versions targeted (so you should make it compatible with Python 2.7 in your case).